# How to override columns number and their width limitation in a tabular layout?

Tags: android, tableview, html

In my application I'm building a TableView in a programmatic way. Table consits of series of single rows with a textview that usually contains a long text (about 80% of screen width) that spans over the following rows with 5 textviews. This worked well, but unfortunately I need to put also a checkbox in these rows with one textbox. Due to length of textbox content, this checkbox has to be placed by the right side and occupy less possible width. However, if I make textbox span only 4 columns, and place checkbox in the space reserved for 5th column, theres too much width for the checkbox, and not enough for the text (it gets wrapped which is bad). I've prepared an example illustrating this situation:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|TextView spanning over 5 columns below             |   <- 1 column spans over 5
|-----+------+---------------+------+---------------|
|col1 | col2 |Column number 3| Col4 | Column number5|   <- 5 columns
|-----+------+---------------+------+---------------|
|This spans over 4 column - not enou|[V]            |
|gh                                 |               |   <- 2 columns, 1st spans over 4
|-----+------+---------------+------+---------------|
|col1 | col2 |Column number 3| Col4 | Column number5|   <- 5 columns
|-----+------+---------------+------+---------------|
|This is what I need-checkbox maximum to right  |[V]|   <- 2 columns
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The last row shows what I need it to look like.
In HTML I would just nest another table inside a row and split width accordingly inside of this new table, but this scenario seems impossible to be built in Android TableLayout.

Does anyone have some idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Another try ;)
Changes are in the properties of the table layout, the text view of the second row, and the layout_gravity of the check box. I suppose that with this elements you will be able to do the same programmatically ;)

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Look the android:shrinkColumns and android:stretchColumns properties of your table. You can edit this properties using:

```
setColumnShrinkable(int columnIndex, boolean isShrinkable)
setColumnStretchable(int columnIndex, boolean isStretchable)
```

It should work using this methods (I've not tested).

Comment: I has a similar idea and even build XML layout that looked exactly how I wanted. However, it requires adding "span" attribute to this nested LineraLayout which works well in XML, but I don't know way to add it programmatically (seems like this parameter is invalid for LinearLayout)...

Comment: Philippe thanks for info but the main problem is to join this 2 column row with 5 column rows when column widths don't exactly match.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand this the first time. Looks harder now ;)
How big must be the 5th row? If you set it to shrinkable, is it going to be too small?

Comment: Yes, 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows are short ones, 2nd and 5th are longer. This is the problem that I cannot afford using whole 5th column width just for checkbox :( I was thinking about adding 6th, narrow, empty column just to hold space for checkbox, but each pixel is valuable...

Comment: I've added above working example with 3 columns instead of 5 but number of columns doesn't really matter. The whole magic is done by nested LinearLayout with added layout_span="3". This is working well, however layout_span seems not to be allowed for LinearLayout and I cannot build it programmatically...